# How to grouping questions into sections and create descriptions in Sharepoint 2007 Surveys

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, survey

I would like to create a SharePoint 2007 survey with an introduction and background to the survey; confidentiality note at the beginning of the survey. I would also like to group questions into sections such as Personal Details (for questions 1 - 6), Training Needs (for questions 7 - 10), Challenges (for questions 11 - 25), etc.

Is there anyone who has achieved this out-of-the-box or with links on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need something quick and dirty I believe you can achieve that by using SharePoint Designer